# PHP Fatal error:Class not found error

Tags: php, namespaces, petri-net

I am following a tutorial for generating pnml files using petrinet framework. I used this [link](https://github.com/ziguss/petrinet) from github and downloaded the php code. However, when I tried to run it locally on my system, I am not able to run due to the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'ziguss\petrinet\Element' not found

This error come when I try to execute the following code (Place.php)

```
<?php

namespace ziguss\petrinet;

class Place extends Element
{
}
```

The Element class is as shown below:

```
<?php

namespace ziguss\petrinet;

abstract class Element
{
    use Nameable;

    protected $inputArcs = [];
    protected $outputArcs = [];

    public function getInputArcs()
    {
        return $this->inputArcs;
    }

    public function addInputArc(Arc $inputArc)
    {
        $this->inputArcs[] = $inputArc;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOutputArcs()
    {
        return $this->outputArcs;
    }


    public function addOutputArc(Arc $outputArc)
    {
        $this->outputArcs[] = $outputArc;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to fix this error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: autoload the class or include it.

Comment: did you include the library? and how did you call the class?

Comment: Which library should be included. Because in the github readme file it does not specify that we have to include any library.